# antd List with react-beautiful-dnd not working smooth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, antd, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using antd's list, and I need it to be rearrangeable. To achieve that, I have implemented react-beautiful-dnd, which is working well. However, I'm facing an issue where my page shrinks and expands while dragging and dropping. Could you please suggest a fix for this problem?

```
          <DragDropContext onDragEnd={() => {}}>
              <Droppable>
                {(provided) => (
                  <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
                    <List
                      dataSource={arrangeResponsesProperties.filter(
                        ({ key }) => key !== "chart"
                      )}
                      renderItem={(responseProperty, index) => (
                        <Draggable
                          draggableId={responseProperty.key}
                          index={index}
                          key={responseProperty.key}
                        >
                          {(provided) => (
                            <div
                              ref={provided.innerRef}
                              {...provided.draggableProps}
                              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                            >
                              <Row align="middle">
                                <Col span={24}>
                                  <Form.Item
                                    name={
                                      responseProperty.key +
                                      "~*!*$*~display_name"
                                    }
                                  >
                                    <Input />
                                  </Form.Item>
                                </Col>
                              </Row>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Draggable>
                      )}
                    />
                    {provided.placeholder}
                  </div>
                )}
              </Droppable>
            </DragDropContext>
```